# Angular 8: send event from one component to sibling component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

I have a sidebar component and a page component.

The sidebar component has a `@ViewChild` which is an `ngbAccordion` from [Angular Boostrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api). I want to trigger its `collapseAll` method *from the page component*.

So the sidebar has

```
  @ViewChild('webAccordion', { static: false })
  webAccordion: NgbAccordion;
  @ViewChild('pageAccordion', { static: false })
  pageAccordion: NgbAccordion;


  collapseAllAccordions() {
    this.webAccordion.collapseAll();
    this.pageAccordion.collapseAll();
  }
```

When the "page" component loads, I want to emit an event to the  "sidebar" component that triggers my `collapseAllAccordions` function.

I know how to do this with parent/child components, and most of the stuff I can find with Google and here on SO discusses parent/child situations.  Except in my case they are **sibling** components. I'm not sure how to hand siblings.

Comment: can you create stackblitz or codesandbox to replicate this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service:

- Inject a service into two sibling components.
- Add an emitter or an Observable to the service.
- Add a function in the service to change the value of the Observable / emit a new value if your using an emitter.
- Use the function in your "page" component.
- Subscribe to the emitter or the Observable in your "sidebar" component and trigger `collapseAllAccordions`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use intermediate singleton service between these components and share the data/actions. For example,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: AppService) { }

  onClick() {
    this.service.collapse();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: AppService) { 
    // Create a observable object which listens to service and 
    // change the behaviour of current page component and vice versa
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

If you require further assistance please create stackblitz or codesandbox to replicate this issue.